# How do I set the iteration path for a workitem in TFS 2015 using TFS API

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

How do I set the Iteration Path field in TFS 2015, using TFS API?
I have been able to set other fields such as; Title, Assigned To, Description, etc.., but not the Iteration Path.

I am setting all the fields passing in JSON.
My app is a Windows Service in Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you set the Iteration Path field in the JSON file? To update the Iteration Path field of a work item, the JSON object should set like this:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
        "value": "TeamProjectName\\Sprint 1"    
    }
]
```

To learn more about Update work item filed using TFS REST API, please look at here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items